# How are the "interesting questions" selected for The Overflow?

Tags: support, questions, newsletter, the-overflow

In [The Overflow #25](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/12/the-overflow-25-new-tools-for-new-times/), a question from Software Engineering Stack Exchange was selected as an "interesting question". Although it's definitely an interesting question, it's not the best reflection of the kind of question that we like to focus on in our community. I'm concerned that selecting questions without input from the communities they come from may result in people getting the wrong impression. If people believe that these highly popular questions are the kinds of questions that should be asked, I can see that generating friction and leading to poor user experience.

What is the process by which a question is selected for the "interesting questions" portion of The Overflow newsletter?

Comment: AFAIK they're hand picked. Which sources Ryan uses to find interesting questions - probably the HNQ list?

Comment: I agree this needs to be addressed. *Many* times, I have seen questions appearing in *The Overview's* curated list that I felt strongly were not good examples of the types of questions that our communities want to encourage (and/or where there are other problems exacerbated by making them so highly visible). If these are being hand-chosen, then they need to at least be reviewed by moderators from the affected sites. (This is leaving aside the bigger problem I have with *The Overflow*, which is that the gloss added by the author is often highly dismissive, disrespectful, or just ill-informed.)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the same process or not, but I've noticed similar selection quality issues with things that get tweeted or posted to Facebook with the #StackOverflowKnows tag. Hopefully staff will comment - I'm not sure if it's worth new question(s) about these other publications or to edit this one to include them.

Comment: @Glorfindel -- It's mostly myself and Medi picking the questions. I can't speak for her, but I use the HNQ a lot to find questions. I try to pick something that's both interesting to me and relevant to technical folks.

Comment: What makes that question interesting, apart from its premise (in that it's not at all obvious that there is a benefit to "one return only") is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For over a decade, Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network have relied on community engagement to dictate what questions and answers bubble to the top. When we pick questions for the newsletter or social media, we choose from a subset that are attracting lots of votes, comments, and conversation.

From that smaller batch, members of the Content team (often with feedback from other teams) pick the questions that we think might have a broad appeal to our readers and social media followers. But hey, that's just our taste. We would absolutely love it if we weren't the only ones picking these questions. That's why we set up a hash tag for it (#StackOverflowKnows), but so far we haven't seen many people tweet any questions at us. We recognize that it would be helpful to have other mechanisms to submit questions so we are setting up an email alias for submissions: stackoverflowknows@stackoverflow.com. If there are other ways you want to surface great questions, please let us know.

Edit: To clarify, this email address is for questions and answers posted on stackoverflow.com or one of the exchanges, not a random question that you think is interesting and hope we're going to answer. Your emails to us should contain a link, not a question.

tl;dr: If you want to suggest questions you think should appear in the newsletter or on our social accounts, please send them to us.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I speak for a lot of people when I say that it's not that we want better questions, but we don't want lower quality questions promoted. HNQ is not reflective of how good a question is for a community. The question from Software Engineering in the last issue of The Overflow was not a good question. Yes, it's on-topic and appropriately scoped and wouldn't be closed, but it's not one that represents us as a community. I'm sure others would say similar things about promoted questions from their communities as well.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Expanded the answer some.

Comment: This is highly helpful. But what can we do about questions that shouldn't be selected appearing? I have been...less than enthused...with some of the selections from Software Engineering. Other communities may also have similar concerns. Maybe the communityathon will help people understand each community better, but could there be more?

Comment: @ThomasOwens I'm curious what your issue is with this and other software engineering questions. Feel free to email us at stackoverflowknows@stackoverflow.com. 

As for what you all can do: most of these get posted on the social channels first. If you think they are a problem, email us and let us know. We can't fix a problem that we don't know exists.

Comment: I'll send an email later on, probably. The short story is they may be interesting to some people, but they aren't the kinds of questions that represent the types of questions most interesting to the community. I'm also not sure what "social channels" you mean, but even a poor representative question going there is not good. Questions selected should not only be interesting, but a good representation of the types of questions that a community wants to see.

Comment: That email address (stackoverflowknows@stackoverflow.com) either doesn't exist or is rejecting emails from people without the right permissions.

Comment: "most of these get posted on the social channels first.": what social channels? Do you mean social media? If so, if since the problem (and it is also a problem for [linux.se], the site I moderate) is that the questions that are tweeted out are bad examples, how will it help if we let you know after they've already been tweeted? Please note that on U&L we have traditionally [downvoted](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3855/) [the community twitter add](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5156/), precisely because it tends to tweet really bad questions that we don't want publicized.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I got IT to lift that restriction. Could you try again?

Comment: @terdon I'm talking about the StackOverflow twitter account and the Facebook/LinkedIn feeds. I'm not familiar with the community-based twitter feeds; I think they may have be automated, but they are from before my time.

Comment: I see, @RyanDonovan, thanks.